# Populate Cells using Drop downlist

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA application, where when I select an option from a drop down list (created using data validation) a few columns should populate automatically. It is working fine if I select an option from the drop down list for each cell individually. However if I drag down an option over a few rows, only the data for the top row gets populated whereas that for the remaining rows do not. How do I tackle this? This is my code under Worksheet_Change function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
If Target.Column = 22 Then
    ThisRow = Target.Row
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    If Target.Value = "E" Then
        range("W" & ThisRow).Value = range("R" & ThisRow).Value
        range("X" & ThisRow).Value = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
    ElseIf Target.Value = "T" Then
        range("W" & ThisRow).Value = ""
        range("X" & ThisRow).Value = range("S" & ThisRow).Value
    ElseIf Target.Value = "M" Then
        range("W" & ThisRow).Value = ""
        range("X" & ThisRow).Value = ""
    ElseIf Target.Value = "N" Then
        range("W" & ThisRow).Value = 0
       range("X" & ThisRow).Value = 0
    ElseIf Target.Value = "R" Then
        range("W" & ThisRow).Value = range("T" & ThisRow).Value
        range("X" & ThisRow).Value = range("U" & ThisRow).Value
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
ExitSub:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're selecting multiple cells, then you have more than one row and/or column in your `Target` range, so statements referencing `.Column` and `.Row` are going to be ambiguous.

If you wrap this code in a loop that steps through each cell within the range, it should update the whole range, not just the first cell.